# "Property status does not exist" error in TypeScript program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

The data.status in the refetchInterval giving error of "property status does not exist"

chatwrapper.tsx

```
const ChatWrapper = ({ fileId }: ChatWrapperProps) => {
  const { data, isLoading } = trpc.getFileUploadStatus.useQuery(
    { fileId },
    {
      refetchInterval: (data) =>
        data?.status === 'SUCCESS' || data?.status === 'FAILED' ? false : 500,
    }
  );
```

index.ts

```
     getFileUploadStatus: privateProcedure
      .input(z.object({ fileId: z.string() }))
      .query(async ({ input, ctx }) => {
        const file = await db.file.findFirst({
          where: {
            id: input.fileId,
            userId: ctx.userId,
          },
        })
  
        if (!file) return { status: 'PENDING' as const }
  
        return { status: file.uploadStatus }
      }),
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` might be `undefined` or null initially when the query is being fetched for the first time.

```
refetchInterval: (data) => data?.status === 'SUCCESS' || data?.status === 'FAILED' ? false : 500,
```

If you're using Typescript, you can improve type safety by defining the possible data structures for the query response.